# JTable Columns names

Tags: java, xml, swing, jtable

How to get column names and write it to XML after moving? `TableModel` set column names by XML file (rewriting onClose table). And I want to my last last modified table writing in XML.

Comment: `How to get column names and write it to XML after moving?` After moving what?

Comment: Column in JTable. Sorry, but i`am called saved method not in proper place. Already all works))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [*How to Use Tables: Creating a Table Model*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data). Your implementation of `getColumnName()` can return the desired `String`. If you make your model a [JavaBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/), you can use [`XMLEncoder`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xmlencoder/info) to convert your `TableModel` into XML text.